# SQL - WooCommerce/Wordpress - Query to list all products ID's containing a specific HTML string located inside product description

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

**Overview**:

I am looking to remove a plugin from my online WooCommerce store with over 2000 products. This plugin required me to insert HTML tags (such as `[table][/table]`) into WooCommerce product descriptions. Since I will be removing the plugin, the tags will no longer work, and the places those tags exist will be broken. I do not know which products have these tags or not, so I am trying to run an SQL query within phpMyAdmin to determine which products will be affected.

**Problem**:

Below is the MySQL query I have obtained from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920234/sql-query-to-include-specific-woocommerce-tag) which displays all products with a specificed tag - this is very close to resolving my issue, but this is not the query I need because this is the tag related to the `term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_tag'` and not HTML tags within product descriptions.

```SQL
SELECT posts.ID AS product_id,
       posts.post_title AS product_title
FROM wp_posts AS posts,
     wp_terms AS terms,
     wp_term_relationships AS term_relationships,
     wp_term_taxonomy AS term_taxonomy
WHERE term_relationships.object_id = posts.ID
  AND term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id
  AND term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
  AND posts.post_type = 'product'
  AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_tag'
  AND terms.slug = 'my-tag-1';
```

**Desired Result**:

Optimally I would like to have a list of all product ID's with this HTML tag `</table>` inside the product description, short description, and additional product tabs, if any.

Your assistance and advice is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to your existing query, add things like this:

```
and 
(product_description like '%</table>%'
or
short_description like '%</table>%'
etc
)
```

Comment: Hello - yes, this seems like the correct solution, however do you know the correct terminology for the `product.description`? SQL query returns this error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'product.description' in 'where clause' `

Comment: The names of tables and fields is something you are supposed to know.  A quick way to find out is to `select * from yourTable where 1=2` and read the column headers.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your help Dan.

Answer (score 1):

This is the following SQL query which resolves my question:

```SQL
SELECT posts.ID AS product_id,
       posts.post_title AS product_title
FROM wp_posts AS posts,
     wp_terms AS terms,
     wp_term_relationships AS term_relationships,
     wp_term_taxonomy AS term_taxonomy
WHERE term_relationships.object_id = posts.ID
  AND term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id
  AND term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
  AND posts.post_type = 'product'
  AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND posts.post_content LIKE '%</mytag>%'
```

Thanks to Dan for the assistance!